# Pandas remove duplicates within the list of values and identifying id's that share the same values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe :

I used to have duplicate test_no ; so I remove the duplicates by

```
df['test_no'] = df['test_no'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(set(x.split(','))))
```

but still as you can see the duplicates are still there ; I think it's due to extra spaces and I want to clean it

Part 1:

```
     my_id              test_no
0   10000000000055910   461511, 461511
1   10000000000064510   528422
2   10000000000064222   528422,528422 , 528421
3   10000000000161538   433091.0, 433091.0
4   10000000000231708   nan,nan
```

Expected Output

```
     my_id              test_no
0   10000000000055910   461511
1   10000000000064510   528422
2   10000000000064222   528422, 528421
3   10000000000161538   433091.0
4   10000000000231708   nan
```

Part 2:

I  also want to check if any of the "my_id" share any of the test_no ;
for example :

```
my_id               matched_myid
10000000000064222  10000000000064510
```

Comment: How about `','.join(set(x.replace(' ','').split(','))`?

Comment: @TimRoberts worked like a charm; thanks. I can see what you did there ; remove the space and then split

Comment: The way to do the second part would be to build a dictionary where the `test_no` was the key, and the `my_id` was the value.  Then you can check if you've seen it before.

Comment: Thanks @Tim for the suggestion. I have done it in a different way but will try our idea as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex to split:

```
import re

df['test_no'] = df['test_no'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(set(re.split(',\s*', x))))

# or
df['test_no'] = [','.join(set(re.split(',\s*', x))) for x in df['test_no']]
```

If you want to keep the original order use `dict.fromkeys` in place of `set`.

If the duplicates are successive you can also use:

```
df['test_no'] = df['test_no'].str.replace(r'([^,\s]+),\s*\1', r'\1', regex=True)
```